# Время продолжительности музыки, и текущее время музыки

Tags: c#

Всем привет, скажите как можно вывести в Label сколько всего времени идёт музыка, и в другой вывести, то где она сейчас играет? Искал в гугле, не нашёл(

Answer (score 1):

Рискну предположить, что сначала нужно извлечь из информации о файле его продолжительность, а затем таймер. На мой взгляд это самый простой вариант, но реализация чего-либо еще может быть муторной